# Angular2.0 router works for components not modules?

Tags: express, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to modify an existing angular app to fit into the structure of this [Starter Project](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter). Anyway, so I have my app module with a submodule (tutorial). Which looks like this:

[image]
When landing on the root domain and then navigating with the router links to `http://localhost:3000/tutorial/chapter/0`, everything works fine. However, if I refresh the page or try to go directly to that link, I get the error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'my-app' is not a known element:
1. If 'my-app' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-app' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("

<body>
    [ERROR ->]<my-app>
        <div class="valign-wrapper">
            <div class="preloader-wrapper active valign"): a@30:4 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse
```

So I believe this is happening because rather than that url linking to the appcomponent, with the tutorial submodule as a child, it's just linking to the TutorialModule, and then the `<my-app></my-app>` tags from the `index.html` aren't recognised. This worked before, so I am not sure what aspect of this new configuration has broken this.

Here is my `app.routes.ts`:

```
import { homeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { pluginsComponent } from './components/plugins/plugins.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: homeComponent },
  { path: 'tutorial', loadChildren: 'tutorial/tutorial.module', pathMatch: 'prefix'},
  { path: 'plugins', component: pluginsComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

and my `tutorial.routes.ts`:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { tutorialComponent }    from './tutorial.component';
import { chapterComponent }  from './chapter/chapter.component';

const tutorialRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tutorial',
    component: tutorialComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'chapter/:id',  component: chapterComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'chapter/0', pathMatch: 'full'},
    ]
  }
];

export const tutorialRouting = RouterModule.forChild(tutorialRoutes);
```

finally in my `app.ts` where I define the express routes I have:

```
app.all(/^\/tutorial$/, (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/tutorial/');
});
app.use('/tutorial/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(resolve(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});
```

to serve the angular index for the tutorial component.

The whole repo is [here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/docs/commit/eca89401a4846dc7e4334d3e933cf587e8225dd0)

Comment: Do you have server side route configured? if not, it will not work. Now to make it work you have to go wiith HashLocationStrategy.

Comment: @micronyks Well I have the final snippet which is an excerpt from my express setup, so I thought that should do it?

Comment: have you tried with HashLocationStrategy?

Comment: @micronyks I would like to use the default strategy, which worked with the same components in my original project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the **index.html** file, I had `<base href=".">` where it should have been `<base href="/">`. I have a bug report [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11873)

Answer (score 0):

@micronyks already said this in the comment but what you need to do a setup your web server to redirect all requests to your index.html page.  Then your app will load and navigate to your "deep" link.

Comment: Yes I know, and I think my express route does that. The issue seems to be that once index.html is served, `my-app` - the selector for app.component is not recognised. I think this is a module thing, as if I do the exact same thing with a child component, everything works fine